# C# WinForms DataGridView Filter error column not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, linq

I have populated *datagridview1* on form load using a html table using the following code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string page = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\data.htm");

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(page);
            List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
                        .Descendants("tr")
                        .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() == 19)
                        .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                        .ToList();
            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = table[0].Count;
            int x = 0;
            foreach (var item in table[0])
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[x].Name = item.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
                x++;
            }
            table.RemoveAt(0);
            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                string[] s = item.ToArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                    s[i] = s[i].Replace("&nbsp;","");
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);
            }
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Material";
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
```

in the form i have a ComboBox where a value is selected, and on a button press i have following code to filter the *datagridview1* based on the selected value

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SelectedIndex = combobox1.SelectedIndex;
        combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string SelectedValue = (string)combobox1.Items[SelectedIndex];

        //DataTable data = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);
        //DataView dvContentDatabase = new DataView(data)
        //{
        //    RowFilter = string.Format("'%{0}%' LIKE '%{1}%'", "Material", "A2B3")
        //};
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dvContentDatabase;

        //this.dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => r.Cells["Material"].Value.ToString() == SelectedValue).ToList().ForEach(row => { if (!row.IsNewRow) row.Visible = false; });

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        bs.Filter = dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + SelectedValue + "%'";
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }
```

i tried several methods which i have remarked on the above code, however the DataGrid view returns a blank row . i have changed the data to match exactly the selected value for testing but still no luck.
i have manually entered value in to the filter instead of using *selectedvalue* still returns a blank row.
any help is really appreciated.

**Updated Code - datatable as datagridview datasource**
As pointed by @JohnG changed the datasoruce, still no luck

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string page = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\drr\Documents\Excel\TBE.htm");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(page);
        List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() == 19)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                    .ToList();
        int columns = 0;
        DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var item in table[0])
        {
            mydt.Columns.Add(item.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            columns++;
        }
        table.RemoveAt(0);
        foreach (var item in table)
        {
            string[] s = item.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                s[i] = s[i].Replace("&nbsp;", "");
            mydt.Rows.Add(s);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = mydt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Material";
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure if the two code snippets match. In the first code snippet, it looks like the code is “manually” adding the rows directly into the grid... `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(s);` … then in the second code snippet the code appears to grab the grids `DataSource`?...  `bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;` … In all the code, I do not see where `datagridView1`’s `DataSouce` is being set. With this I would assume the filter is producing nothing since the data source is empty.

Comment: @rellik, can you give an example about the related html? It may help me to make a test.

Comment: @JohnG thanks for pointing this out, i will put the data in to a datatable and use it as the datasource for the datagridview. will let you know how it works out soon.

Comment: Hi @jack-j-jun-msft sorry i didn't had the time to change the data as there are proprietary information in the table. but i managed to find a solution which i have posted below. thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string page = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\drr\Documents\Excel\TBE.htm");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(page);
        List<List<string>> table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
                    .Descendants("tr")
                    .Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Count() == 19)
                    .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
                    .ToList();
        int columns = 0;
        DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var item in table[0])
        {
            string ColumnNames = (item.Replace("&nbsp;", ""));
            mydt.Columns.Add(item.Replace(ColumnNames.ToString(), ""));
            mydt.Columns[columns].ColumnName = ColumnNames.ToString();
            mydt.AcceptChanges();
            columns++;
        }
        table.RemoveAt(0);
        foreach (var item in table)
        {
            string[] s = item.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                s[i] = s[i].Replace("&nbsp;", "");
            mydt.Rows.Add(s);
        }
        DGV_SAPData.DataSource = mydt;
        DGV_SAPData.Columns[1].Name = "Material";
        BTN_Print.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Thank you @JohnG for pointing me to the right direction, of course there maybe an easier or simple way of doing this, please share if you find other solutions.